# Winter tires 195/55r16 fit on a 16x7 rim

Tags: tires, winter, wheels

Hello I was wondering if I can use winter tires 195/55r16 on a 16x7 rim? Or can I use another 195/ which fit better ?

Answer (score 1):

The only 2 concerns about fitting a tire to a wheel are the diameter (they must be a perfect match), and the width (there's a range of widths that will fit).

In your case, you are fitting a 16" tire into a 16" wheel, so we only need to look at the width. According to [image: this chart], 195 is the minimum width you can fit safely on a 7" wide wheel. Any 195 width tire will fit the same, changing the aspect ratio will only mess-up your speedometer and odometer.

Is 195/55R16 your OEM tire size?

Comment: On my Mercedes are the 16x7 rims and want to install 195/55r16 just want to make sure that will not course Amy problem. I have notice buying 195 are cheaper and better in snow

Comment: What is your OEM tire size? You need to make sure the circumference still matches.

Comment: My regular size tire is 205/55r16